# Is it correct to use the word "final" if there are only two items in the list?

Tags: word-usage

Google's definition of final:

> final
>   1. coming at the end of a series.

I'm a bit hesitant to use final in a two-item list. Because two items isn't enough to make a series, I think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a two-item list, it is the usual practice to refer to the first of the two as "the former" and to the second of the two as "the latter."